# Multiple Conditions in RectNative shows two conditions in the same time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, algorithm

**component1** should show up if options is less than 4.
**component2** should show up if options is more than 4.
**component3** should show up if options is more than 7.
Right now if my options array has less than 4 values it displays together component1 with component3. Why is that so?

```
<View>
{options.length < 4 && (
<Component1
 options={options}
/>
)}
{options.length > 4 && (
<Component2 options={options}/>
)}
{options.length < 7 && (
<Component3 options={options}/>
)}
</View>
```

Comment: something is wrong with third condotion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code you need to check for multiple conditions if there is any

```js
      <View>
        {options.length < 4 && 
          <Component1 options={options} />
        }
        {options.length > 4 && options.length < 7 && (
          <Component2 options={options} />
        )}
        {options.length > 7 && 
          <Component3 options={options} />
        }
      </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<View>
{options.length < 4 && (
<Component1 options={options}/>
)}
{options.length > 4 && (
<Component2 options={options}/>
)}
{options.length > 7 && (     // change your code here
<Component3 options={options}/>
)}
</View>
```

Comment: thanks, but got the same result

Comment: check my updated code